# "what ... for" vs "for what ..."

Tags: questions

I know that the next sentence is correct:

> **What** are you going to use it **for**?

But I was wondering if the following one would be correct as well:

> **For what** are you going to use it?

*I had a conversation with my friend where he had noticed my wrong use of the second sentence. Was his remark right?*

Comment: First, "going **to** use it". Second, be idiomatic not idiosyncratic.

Comment: @MvLog, I am not a native speaker, so I don't know which way is idiomatic

Comment: You asked essentially the same question before. The normal way of saying it is the former.

Comment: @userr2684291, is the second sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, it is, but it sounds very formal indeed. Michael Swan: In a more formal style, a preposition is often put earlier in questions and relative structures, before the question word or relative pronoun. _With whom did she go?_  Even in a very formal style, prepositions are not often put at the beginning of questions which have be as the main verb.
_Who is it for, madam?_ (NOT _For whom is it?_)

Comment: Yes, the second one is incorrect. 'What.. For' is a fixed structure and the prepostion cannot be fronted. If you don't want to end your sentence with a preposition, just use 'why'.

Comment: The second one is correct, but it's formal. I would also say that you could be formal and say "Whom is it for?", but never "For whom is it?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is a bit interesting. In *super-duper-perfect grammarian's English,* the **second** sentence would be the **only** correct sentence, as it's technically incorrect to end a sentence with a conjunction or preposition. As MvLog pointed out, this rule is dated and archaic, so few people strictly adhere to it.

**In addition**, pretty much **everyone** who speaks English would use your first sentence. It just sounds more natural.

So to sum up: the first one **sounds** the best (and is the one you should use), while the second is *technically* grammatically correct.

Comment: for is a preposition here

Comment: @MvLog That it is. Post edited.

Comment: **From Garner's Modern American Usage 3rd Ed.**  The spurious rule about not ending sentences with prepositions is a remnant of Latin grammar, in which a preposition was the one word that a writer could not end a sentence with. Winston Churchill’s witticism about the absurdity of this bugaboo should have laid it to rest. When someone once upbraided him for ending a sentence with a preposition, he rejoined, “That is the type of arrant pedantry up with which I shall not put.” Avoiding a preposition at the end of the sentence sometimes leads to just such a preposterous monstrosity.

Comment: @MvLog Thanks for the additional info. I've edited again accordingly

Comment: @MvLog Most likely a misattribution: http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html